# Haskell autocompletion in Emacs using haskell-mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, autocomplete, haskell-mode

I installed `haskel-mode` in emacs. Then I write in my .emacs:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/haskell-mode/haskell-site-file")
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-font-lock-symbols t)
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
```

What must I add in my conf file that emacs could autocomplete for Haskell? Or Haskell mode there is no such possibility?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When there is no language-specific support, you can use **tags**. This is a generic completion mechanism.

1. Generate a `TAGS` file, which contains a list of identifiers and where they are defined. Emacs comes with the `etags` program to do this in many languages, but not Haskell; ghc comes with [`hasktags`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/utils.html#hasktags).
2. Load the `TAGS` file with `M-x visit-tags-table`.

Tags are not context-dependent, so they'll indiscriminately suggest types, values, constructors, etc everywhere. They also won't provide advanced features such as easily showing the type of a value. The most important tags commands are:

- `M-TAB` (`complete-symbol`) completes an identifier according to the loaded list of tags.
- `M-.` (`find-tag`) goes to the place where the identifier at point is defined, opening the containing file if necessary.
- `M-*` (`pop-tag-mark`) goes back where you were before `M-.`.
- `M-x tags-apropos` shows a list of identifiers matching a regexp.

For more information, look under "Tags" in the Emacs manual.

---

For an even cruder, but fully automatic mechanism, there is the **dynamic abbrev** feature. `C-M-/` (`dabbrev-completion`) looks in most open buffers for a completion; this is completely language-independent, so it'll even find words in strings, comments, whatever. `M-/` (`dabbrev-expand`) is similar, but directly completes to the nearest match before point.

Answer (score 11):

[ghc-mod](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/) provides some completion for Haskell within Emacs, as well as checking with hlint and ghc. In combination with M-/, it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 8):

`haskell-mode` currently provides no such possibility. There is some work on implementation of haskell parser for CEDET - in this case, users will get autocompletion features automatically. But this work had started not so much time ago...

Comment: Do you know how work on CEDET for Haskell has been progressing?

Answer (score 7):

My [setup](http://github.com/wh5a/arch) is a little more complicated. It uses the [auto-complete](http://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete) infrastructure which 
shows a dropdown list of candidates automatically similar to traditional IDEs. I downloaded [this script](http://github.com/wh5a/arch/blob/master/Emacs/auto-complete-haskell.el) that hardcodes all the keywords. In addition to that, I use [ghc-mod](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/) to generate module names.

Answer (score 6):

As a "cheap and cheerful" autocompletion mechanism, don't overlook `M-/`.  It's completely heuristic and language-independent, but surprisingly effective.

Answer (score 2):

Besides autocompletion for your own code, you can also get autocompletion (with apidocs even) for the standard library, import names, and pragma names using [company-ghc](https://github.com/iquiw/company-ghc). I found [this guide](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#completion-with-company-ghc) to be very helpful. Note, I didn't get it to work fully for myself yet, but I can feel I'm close :-)