# Autocomplete function name in haskell-mode

Tags: emacs, haskell

had a system crash and my .emacs got lost. Before the crash, haskell-mode auto completed function names when pressing tab button on a new line. Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour in my new .emacs.

Any one got a clue on how to enable this behaviour?

Comment: This is a feature of one of the Haskell indentation modes.  They have confusingly similar names, so I forget which one it is.  Try each of them until you find the one you're used to.

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424697/haskell-autocompletion-in-gnu-emacs, read all the answers there?

Comment: Shouldn't this solution be posted as an answer? That way the question can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/haskell-mode/haskell-site-file") (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent)
```

solved my problem