# Haskell autocompletion with general info and documentation in Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, autocomplete, haskell-mode

I recently started learning Haskell and switched over to Emacs as well.

I've installed `haskell-mode`.

This is what my `haskell` section in my `.emacs` file looks like

```
  79   (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'font-lock-mode)                                                    
  80   (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)                                          
  81   (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ghc)                                                     
  82   (custom-set-variables                                                                            
  83    '(haskell-stylish-on-save t))
```

What I want to know is: if it's possible to get an IDE like autocomplete feature in emacs, where partially typing a function (user defined/from imported packages/from base) shows you its type and general info like you can get from `hoogle` search?

A brief search got me to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424697/haskell-autocompletion-in-emacs-using-haskell-mode/3432226) which has a latest answer from 2014. I'm not sure if things have changed since.

I also found out about `tags` with `hasktags` or `fast-tags` but I'm not sure how to apply those methods to get autocomplete suggestions from imported packages or getting doc about written functions.

Comment: You may like to install [haskell-ide-engine and integrate it with emacs](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine#user-content-using-hie-with-emacs). Autocompletion is a part of HIE among some other useful Haskell thingies.

Comment: Intero also does autocompletion with emacs. No integrated docs, AFAIK.

Comment: @Redu Would you mind giving some general direction on how to go about installing it and making it work? I've installed hie from my package manager `arch's aur` and also generated hoogle db. `(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/path/to/lsp-mode/")
(require 'lsp-mode)
(require 'lsp-ui)
(require 'lsp-haskell)
(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook #'lsp-haskell-enable)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)` are the hooks I added. But autocomplete doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Please try to use intero, whit this configuration: https://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/